# система строительства, как в clash of clans в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как создать систему строительства на С# в Unity на подобии системы строительства, как в  clash of clans? Нужно создать саму сетку строительства на которую будут ставится разные здания.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно создать карту в 2d, на которой будет размещаться модели в перспективе 2.5d. [Здесь](http://matov.me/2016/02/11/isometric-2-5d-toolset-v2-3-released/) вы можете посмотреть как это сделать.

Comment: спасибо большое)))

Comment: @MiheyVolk еще на эту тему есть [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/269653/) на хабре которая описывает действия.

Comment: за статью тоже отдельное спасибо)

Comment: @MiheyVolk: Если ответ вам помог, поставьте зелёную галку слева.